# Explain a Mathematica winning one-liner

Tags: syntax

```
Dynamic[Refresh[
  Graphics3D[
   Sphere[l -= 
     MapIndexed[
      Plus @@ (Function[
           x, (d = # - x)/(d = Sqrt[d.d]) Log@d/2^(2 + 2 d)] /@ 
          Drop[l, #2]) &, l], E^-1]], UpdateInterval -> 1],
  l = RandomReal[7, {21, 3}]]
```

This code is from a past one-liner winner. I'm new to *Mathematica* and can't understand it. Can some one explain the code in ordinary language terms? I searched all the functions in the help, know `@@`, `/@` do and currently am reading Dynamics Tutorial from Wolfram.

Comment: Suggestion ... Start learning Dynamics with easier examples :)

Comment: Hi, the code is here. http://blog.wolfram.com/2010/12/17/the-mathematica-one-liner-competition/

There are a whole bunch of amazing code. I think he left out the UpdateInterval to save space since there is a character requirement.

Comment: This is one really impressive one-liner!

Comment: There is another very interesting physical simulation from [Mathematica One-Liner Competition 2012](http://www.wolfram.com/training/special-event/mathematica-experts-live-one-liner-competition-2012/): `r:=.5-Random[];
p=Array[{8^9 {r,r},r+.5}&,99];
Dynamic@Graphics[
Disk@@@(p={#2 #1+{r,r}+(1-#2)MousePosition["Graphics",#1],#2}&@@@p),
PlotRange->44
]`. It is interactive.

Answer (score 17):

OK, the verbal description isn't very easy, but I'll try:

This is a simulation showing how the attractive forces between `21` spheres cause them to aggregate. Instead of simulating the equations of motion, the `Dynamic` approximates the physics of the attractive force and the repulsive core in the somewhat artificial body of `Function[{x}, ...]`.

Its argument `x` is a three-dimensional position of a sphere in the list `l` containing `21` randomly generated starting locations. Relative to this position `x`, the attraction due to the *other* spheres is calculated and collected in a list. The `Drop` statement in the coordinate list which is injected into the `Function` (via the mapping `/@`) makes sure that the sphere doesn't try to attract *itself*. The argument of `Drop` is the index of the sphere we're currently looking at, provided as `#2` by the `MapIndexed` statement inside which the `Function` appears.

In addition to the attraction, we want to get zero force at a certain minimum distance, for which temporarily the variable `d` is used inside `Function`. This is achieved with the help of the `Log@d` term. `d` becomes the inter-sphere distance by forming `d = Sqrt[d.d]` where on the *right-hand* side `d` was  initially a *vectorial* difference between two spheres represented by `d=#-x`.

The `Plus@@` part is just the step in which the contributions of the attractive forces that were collected as a list are then all added up.

The `Dynamic` is updated repeatedly and leads to an animation because during the display the actual coordinate list `l` is modified by `l -= ...` which subtracts from each coordinate in `l` an incremental displacement proportional to the net force on the sphere at that location. Comparing this to Newton's equation of motion, $\vec{F} = m \vec{a}$, something akin to this behavior arises if you assume there is an additional damping force. But the algorithm doesn't contain that explicitly - it's "fake physics" just trying to look physical. We are using for each coordinate $\vec{x}_i$ in the list `l` the approximation $\vec{x}_i = \vec{x}_i + \vec{v} \Delta t$ where the time interval $\Delta t$ could be considered to be unity. The instantaneous velocity $\vec v$ is assumed to be proportional to the resultant "force" on particle $i$.

Comment: +1 I never thought it could be done in less than a few pages

Comment: That was a great explanation! I understand it a lot better now. Thanks!

Comment: Why is #2 gets rid of the self attraction?

I'm not sure what the "&, l" and "l -=" part do.

Comment: @Nasser Ok, you just made me listen to a machine speak out 63 real numbers. There's got to be some retribution for this... :P

Comment: @fizzix The `#` represents the coordinates of a sphere in the list `l` and `#2` represents its index. `Drop[l,#2]` is the coordinates of all the other spheres in 'l`.

Comment: @fizzix Sorry, had to leave the computer for a while... I'll trey to clean it up now.