# Pretty way to group elements at odd and even positions

Tags: list-manipulation

How to make a function that splits list elements by odd and even positions? Shortest implementation wins. I myself came up with:

```
splitOdds[x_] := 
 Extract[x, {#}\[Transpose]] & /@ GatherBy[Range@Length@x, OddQ]
```

And:

```
splitOdds[x_] := Flatten[Partition[#, 1, 2]] & /@ {x, Rest@x}

splitOdds[{a, b, c, d, e, f}]
(*{{a, c, e}, {b, d, f}}*)
```

Comment: You can use `Span` e.g. `Range[10][[;; ;; 2]]` and `Range[10][[2 ;; ;; 2]]`

Comment: The title and the text description of this question suggests something completely different. Further users will definitely be confused why you are not gathering even/odd elements, but elements on even/odd positions instead.

Comment: @halirutan I agree; I'll change it.

Comment: How about `Part[A, #] & /@ GatherBy[Range@Length@lst, OddQ]`

Comment: Well, `TakeDrop[#, {1, -1, 2}] &` since V10.2.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A couple for fun:

```
lst = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g};

Partition[lst, 2, 2, 1, {}] ~Flatten~ {2}
```

> ```
> {{a, c, e, g}, {b, d, f}}
> ```

```
i = 1; GatherBy[lst, i *= -1 &]
```

> ```
> {{a, c, e, g}, {b, d, f}}
> ```

And my Golf entry:

```
lst[[# ;; ;; 2]] & /@ {1,2}
```

> ```
> {{a, c, e, g}, {b, d, f}}
> ```

---

And here is an anti-Golf "Rube Goldberg" solution:

```
ReleaseHold[List @@ Dot @@ 
  PadRight[{Hold /@ lst, {}}, Automatic, #]] & /@
    Permutations[Range[1, 0, -1]]
```

> ```
> {{a, c, e, g}, {b, d, f}}
> ```

Comment: It's brilliant!

Comment: @swish Thanks. :-)

Comment: Alright. It would be hard to beat but let's see.

Answer (score 21):

Less than sensible, more than pretty, hopefully enjoyable, with a different notion of grouping.  Based in part on [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17232/explain-a-mathematica-winning-one-liner).  Gives a new meaning to bubble sort.

[image: Movie of grouping]
[image: Movie of grouping]

```
list = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g(*, h, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t*)};

likeElements[list_, {idx_}] /; OddQ[idx] := list[[1 ;; ;; 2]]; 
likeElements[list_, {idx_}] /; EvenQ[idx] := list[[2 ;; ;; 2]];
coords = Transpose[{Range[#], RandomReal[{-0.01, 0.01}, #], RandomReal[{-0.01, 0.01}, #]}] &@Length[list]; 

Dynamic[
 Refresh[Module[{d},
   Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[
     coords -= MapIndexed[
       Total[Function[x, (d = # - x)/(d = Sqrt[d.d]) Log@d/2^(2 + 2 Sqrt[d])] /@ 
           Drop[likeElements[coords, #2], Ceiling[#2/2]]] + 
         Total[Function[x, -(d = # - x)/(d = Sqrt[d.d])^2 (d - 1/E) (1 - d/7)/2^(2 + 2 d)] /@ 
           likeElements[coords, #2 + 1]] &, coords],
    {MapIndexed[Text[Style[#1, ColorData[2][Mod[First[#2], 2]]], First[#2]] &, list],
     Opacity[0.3], Sphere[Range@Length[list], E^-1]}], 
    PlotRange -> {{-1.5, Length[list] + 1.5}, 4 {-1, 1}, 4 {-1, 1}}]
   ],
  UpdateInterval -> 1]]
```

Tweaking the coefficients slightly changes the behavior, which is also somewhat dependent on the length of the list.  Won't win a speed contest.

The two `Total[Function...]` expressions calculate the new positions based on like elements (same parity) attract (first `Total`) and unlike repel (second `Total`).

Answer (score 17):

You can also use `Downsample`, which is new in version 9:

```
lst = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g};
Downsample[lst, 2, #] & /@ {1, 2}
(* {{a, c, e, g}, {b, d, f}} *)
```

Comment: Oh neat, one new useful function learned.

Comment: +1 Nice.  I hadn't found `Downsample` yet.

Comment: Is this function any faster than `Part` and `Span`, or `Take`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard in my quick test, MMA 9.0.1, for packed arrays, better to worse, `Downsample`- `Part`- `Take`, but not for much. For unpacked, the opposite order

Comment: Thanks.  It sounds like my old friend `Part` is still a good universal choice. :-)

Answer (score 13):

Since all the sensible answers have already been done...

```
lst ~(•=#;Cases)~(_/;(•=!•))&/@{!#,#}&[_==_]
```

Comment: Oh great! Now this is going to start an obfuscated mma trend!

Comment: This is really great.  It's not often I have to do a double-take on syntax. :-O

Comment: Will it `rm -rf /*` my disk? :)

Comment: @swish I promise to not do anything to your disk ;)

Comment: Ok, you've just got my wtf, I mean +1. I still haven't parsed it ...

Answer (score 10):

My way:

```
lst = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g};    

Take[lst, {#, -1, 2}] & /@ {1, 2}
```

> ```
> {{a, c, e, g}, {b, d, f}}
> ```

Comment: That's mine, just longer. :-p

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ha, I've just seen now that in the docs for `Span` it says `m[[i;;j;;k]]` is equivalent to `Take[m,{i,j,k}]`. Well, let's say that mine is more readable for novice users.

Comment: Indeed it is.  I'm just poking fun. :-)

Comment: By the way, try your hand at a "Rube Goldberg" solution.  I had fun with mine, though it could be considerably more complicated...

Comment: I just timed these and `Take` is slightly faster. +1 for pragmatism.

Comment: How about also adding `Drop` method to it for completion?

Comment: @swish you mean like: `lst ~#~ {1, -1, 2}] & /@ {Take, Drop}`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No, I meant `Drop[lst, {#, -1, 2}] & /@ {2, 1}`. Basically replace `Take` with `Drop`.

Answer (score 6):

Here is another one, based on `Reap` and `Sow`:

```
Reap[MapIndexed[Sow[#1, Mod[#2, 2]] &, lst], _, #2 &][[2]]
```

This one has an advantage to be easily generalizable to more complex conditions, although certainly not the fastest one here.

Comment: That looks too complicated.  I would write: `Reap[# ~Sow~ Mod[#2, 2] & ~MapIndexed~ lst][[2]]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, you can skip the pattern on `Reap`. But, generally, I am in the habit of keeping it, since I often use `Reap` with some tags just for safety.

Answer (score 6):

I'll join in with my own version:

```
splitList[list_] := Pick[list, 
    IntegerDigits[1/6 (-3 - (-1)^#1 + 2^(2 + #1)) &@Length@list, 2], #] & /@ {1, 0}

splitList[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g}]
(* {{a, c, e, g}, {b, d, f}} *)
```

This uses the fact that the "selector pattern" or "sieve" for the elements proceeds as

$$1, 10, 101, 1010, 10101,... $$

and the general term (in base 10) for the binary sequence above is $\frac{1}{6}(2^{2+n}-(-1)^n-3)$, where $n$ is the length of your list.

The selector pattern can also be generated more straightforwardly as:

```
Riffle[ConstantArray[1, Ceiling[Length@list/2]], 0]
```

Comment: Equivalently: `splitList[l_List] := With[{n = Length[l]}, Pick[l, IntegerDigits[Ceiling[2 (2^n - 1)/3], 2, n], #] & /@ {1, 0}]`

Answer (score 5):

**Method 1**: `GatherBy` each element's position (even or odd).

```
GatherBy[lst, Mod[Position[lst,#],2]&]
```

> {{a, c, e, g}, {b, d, f}}

---

**Method 2**: Using `ArrayReshape` (version 9).

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In the following, the MathematicaIcon is used for padding in the reshaping of the array. After the array is reshaped, the icons are removed.
Any element can be used in lieu of the MathematicaIcon, provide that one is certain that the padding element is not in the original list.

```
 ArrayReshape[lst,{Length[lst],2},"\[MathematicaIcon]"]\[Transpose]
 /."\[MathematicaIcon]"->Sequence[]
```

---

**Method 3**: Check whether each index from `MapIndexed` is even or odd.

```
GatherBy[MapIndexed[List,lst],OddQ]/.{x_,{_}}:> x
```

Answer (score 4):

Base on `Pick`:

```
gather[list_] := Pick[{list, list}, Take[#, Length@list] & /@ {#, RotateLeft[#]} &@
  Mod[Range@Ceiling[Length@list, 2], 2], 1];

gather[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g}]
```

> ```
> {{a, c, e, g}, {b, d, f}}
> ```

Comment: `g` is in both your output lists!

Answer (score 2):

```
# & @@@ # & /@ GatherBy[MapIndexed[{#, OddQ@#2} &, lst], Last]
#[[All, 1]] & /@ GatherBy[MapIndexed[{#, OddQ@#2} &, lst], Last]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i do it:

> GetEvenStep[list_] := Partition[list, 2][[All, 1]]

> GetOddStep[list_] := Partition[list, 2][[All, 2]]

Be careful, depending on the list you want to split you might want to flip the names!