# How do I perform the riffle function backward?

Tags: list-manipulation

I know riffle will combine the lists {1,2,3} and {a,b,c} to be {1,a,2,b,3,c}. Is there a way to work backward and split the list {a,b,c,d,e,f} to be {a,c,e} and {b,d,f}?

Comment: `{a,b,c,d,e,f}[[#;;;;2]]&/@{1,2}`

Comment: `Transpose[Partition[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, 2]]`

Comment: @belisarius (& nikie) Why don't you post an answer?

Comment: @Szabolcs b/c I don't fully understand the question. Specifically, what has `Riffle[]` to do with `Part[]`?

Comment: @belisarius As I understand it (based on the example, which seems clear), yours is a good solution.  Get back `x` and `y` from the result of `Riffle[x,y]`, provided that `x` and `y` are of the same length.

Comment: Unless you intended something more generalized this is a duplicate of [(21468)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21468) so I am closing it as such.

Answer (score 6):

You may want to try

```
ClearAll[unRiffle];
unRiffle[{}] = {{}, {}};
unRiffle[x_List] := x[[# ;; ;; 2]] & /@ {1, 2}
{lOdd, lEven} = unRiffle[{a, b, c, d, e, f}]
(*
 {{a, c, e}, {b, d, f}}
*)
```

Comment: Bad alternative: `Rest@Extract[list, {{}, {;; ;; 2}, {2 ;;  ;; 2}}]`

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun:

```
ClearAll[unRiffle];
unRiffle[{a_, l___}, {x___}, y_] := unRiffle[{l}, y, {x, a}];
unRiffle[{}, x_, y_] := {x, y};
unRiffle[l_List] := unRiffle[l, {}, {}];
```