# Selecting every n-th element from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a list:

```
data = {4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 13, 12};
```

I want to take those elements in the list which are located at equal distances, say, every third element, getting the list `{7, 5, 1, 12}`. Can anyone suggest a way of doing this for a list having large number of elements.

Comment: `l[[n;;-1;;n]]` ?

Comment: Could you please explain how does it work?

Comment: I would advice for solutions based on extended syntax, which are easier to understand than runes.

Comment: @Suren Did you follow the links from my answer and read the documentation?

Comment: Now it becomes clear. Thank you everyone for your prompt handling.

Comment: This question is nicely addressed in the documentation: [Getting Pieces of Lists](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GettingPiecesOfLists.html).

Comment: how would the code change if you want to take every third number starting on the second element instead of the first?

Comment: Closely related: [(21468)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21468/121)

Answer (score 38):

Please look up [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html) and [`Span`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Span.html).

You can use

```
data[[ ;; ;; n]]
```

Comment: This is one of those questions that are easily answered using the documentation and should be closed as such, but at the same time would probably  be really useful for new users (if only for the clear question title).

Comment: @YvesKlett: Could you link to where you found this easily in the documentation?

Comment: @ raxacoricofallapatorius Fifth entry in https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Span.html

Comment: Having looked through the documentation, I didn't find it, only after finding this question, I knew what to look for.

Comment: @YvesKlett - Out of the hundreds of names for functions, how are we supposed to know that 'span' is what we're looking for?  I mean, it doesn't even have a name, it's like part of the list syntax.

Comment: @Quarkly werll, it does feature prominently in the `Part` documentation. On the other side, `Mathematica` is not really ... parsimonious with new function names, and I keep running into really, really useful functions I did not know about regularly.

Comment: My point is: StackExchange/Google is a far more useful resource than Mathematica documentation because it's organized the way humans think about finding solutions.  Why would you want to make Stack Exchange a less useful tool?

Comment: @Yves    I was able to find "  ;; " in the mathematica documentation, but I can't understand what it means when you leave a blank in data[[ ;; ;; n]].  The documentation doesn't  seem to describe a blank space.  Please help.

Answer (score 12):

I'm surprised that this has not come up:

```
Last /@ Partition[data, 3]
```

Before `Span` (and version 6), I used it **a lot**.

Answer (score 9):

As well as `Part` an `Span`, you could also use `Take`.

```
data = {4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 13, 12};
data[[3 ;; -1 ;; 3]]
Take[data, {3, -1, 3}]
```

Both give

> ```
> {7, 5, 1, 12}
> ```

Answer (score 9):

[**Downsample**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Downsample.html):

> **Downsample**[*array*, *n* ] 
>   returns a downsampled version of the *array* by sampling every *n*'th element.

```
Downsample[data, 3]
```

> {4, 8, 3, 2}

**Partition** with offset

```
Flatten @ Partition[data, 1, 3]
```

> {4, 8, 3, 2}

Comment: Introduced in version 9 and I discover it only now. Definitely the most direct implementation of the answer the OP wanted.

Answer (score 5):

Your data

```
data = {4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 13, 12}
```

Let's say you want every third starting by the second element, that means you want parts `{2, 5, 8, 11}`. we get those indexes using [`Range`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Range.html)

```
Range[2, Length[data], 3]
```

> ```
> {2, 5, 8, 11}
> ```

Now we use this indexes with [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html)

```
Part[data, Range[2, Length[data], 3]]
```

> ```
> {5, 9, 2, 13}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Lots of other great answers here but this is another way

```
Table[data[[i]], {i, 3, Length@data, 3}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
data = {4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 13, 12};
sel = Partition[Range[3, Length@data, 3], 1]
Extract[data, sel]
```

But I'm sure there are shorter ways.