# How to take every second element

Tags: list-manipulation

If I have `{1,2,3,4,5,6}`, how do I take all the second elements into a new list? So I want a list like `{2,4,6}`.

Comment: `list={1,2,3,4,5,6}; list[[2;; ;;2]]`. `Extract[list, Range[2,Length@list,2]`. `Partition[list, 2][[All, 2]]`. Etc.

Comment: If you search the docs for "take every second element", the first hit is `Take`, which is the function. If you use the free-form input to "take every second element from `list`", you get `%[[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]]`, which is easily adapted.

Comment: The function that march and Patrick are referring to is `Span`, just type `?Span` into your notebook to get the information on how to use it.

Comment: Guy, we should re-open [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64003/12), and make it a canonical version.  Then mark this one as a duplicate.  This might not be *that* easy to find for a beginner actually ...

Answer (score 5):

The keywords are [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html) (`[[ ... ]]`) and [`Span`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Span.html) (`;;`).

Simply use

```
list[[2;; ;; 2]]
```