# Deleting continuous pairs in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

How can we remove some arbitrary continuous pairs (`n`) in a list containing many pairs. For example:

```
list=RandomInteger[{1, 3}, {20, 2}];
(our random) list= (**{{1, 3}, {1, 1}, {3, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 1}, {3, 3},
  {2,  1}, {2, 3}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {1, 2}, {3, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 1}, 
 {1, 1}, {3, 1}, {2, 2}, {1, 1}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}}**)
```

We wish to have :

```
for n=3 {{1, 3}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}};
for n=4 {{1, 3}, {3, 3}, {1, 2}, {3, 1}};
```

Comment: Do you mean `list[[1 ;; ;; 4]]` and `list[[1 ;; ;; 5]]`? But the second expected result is different. I am wondering how you obtained `n=4`

Comment: Yes I corrected that. Thank you.

Comment: Related: [Selecting every n-th element from a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64003).