# Rearrange a Nx2 list into a 2 arrays of length N

Tags: list-manipulation

Mathematica newbie here, thanks for your patience.  I have a list of 2-element lists, i.e.

```
{{x1,y1}, {x2,y2}, ... {xn,yn}}
```

But I want to rearrange them so that they are two lists of N elements, i.e.

```
{{x1,x2, ... xn},{y1,y2, ... yn}}
```

I'm sure this is child's play for most of you, but it's really giving me trouble.  I found another page that I thought would be a solution:
[Pretty way to group elements at odd and even positions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21468/pretty-way-to-group-elements-at-odd-and-even-positions)

The answers there take a flat list `{x1,y1,x2,y2, ... xn,yn}` and produce the output that I want.  But I need to flatten my list first.  But when I call Flatten inside of one of those functions it doesn't work.  The authors of the solutions have used MMA magic which I do not yet comprehend.  So here are some examples of my modifications of the solutions from the page linked above which do not work:

```
unzip[listoftuples_] :=
 Take[Flatten[listoftuples], {#, -1, 2}] & /@ {1, 2}

unzip[listoftuples_] :=
 Flatten[listoftuples][[# ;; ;; 2]] & /@ {1, 2}

unzip[listoftuples_] := 
 Downsample[Flatten[listoftuples], 2, #] & /@ {1, 2}
```

Yet if I remove `Flatten[]` from any of those solutions and instead call `Flatten[]` outside of that function, i.e. `unzip[Flatten[data]]` then it works.  MMA is obviously powerful and flexible, but really confusing and cryptic to newcomers.

Comment: This is an ideal job for `Transpose`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the simple solution!  But neither of you can get credit for it since you didn't officially answer it.

Comment: Scott, I see the questions at the end of your post might be more interesting to answer (& I do not know with confidence what the answer is). Perhaps you can edit your question to match those (more interesting IMO) questions?

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the last paragraph. I did this and got the same results: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyP4Y.png — You should make sure you start a function definition with something like `ClearAll[unzip]` to be sure you are starting over. Symbols in Mma are allowed to have multiple definitions. It something that new users don't always appreciate (e.g. that a typo persists and causes a bug).